# Nested data filter in CoreData?

Tags: ios, swift, core-data

Is it possible to filter the data in CoreData?
Using predicate I have sorted by name.
But I need to sort by date, make a selection of payments per month, for example.

There are two entities:

```
CategoriesEntity
name:String

TransactionsEntity:
sum: Double
date: Date
note: String
```

when filtering i get a list by category

```
let predicate = filterKey.isEmpty ? nil : NSPredicate(format: "name CONTAINS[cd] %@", filterKey)
fetchRequest = FetchRequest<T>(entity: T.entity(), sortDescriptors: [], predicate: predicate)
```

but how can I take transactions by date from the request if it is a nested entity in the entity category?

upd:  categories and transactions are connected One-to-many

Comment: I currently don't see the relation between `CategoryEntity` & `TransactionsEntity`, it's hard to tell. But filtering for a month, it's filtering the date that are after the beginning of the month, and before the end of the month. Is that the logic you are looking for?

Comment: Yes.
For example, when dealing with an array, I would do something like this:

          var filtredToDate: [TransactionEntity] = []
        for category in categories {
            let currentDateTransactions =  category.transactionsArray.filter({$0.date! == date})
            filtredToDate += currentDateTransactions
            
        }
apart from the fact that you need to compare the range of dates, but in the example you can see that I can access transactions and count them

Comment: So category can have one or multiple `TransactionsEntity`, that's what was missing in your question. There was no link between them.

Comment: I'm sorry, I forgot to mention this aspect yes categories and transactions are connected One-to-many

Comment: And what do you expect if there is for a category C, it has a transaction T1 in monthA, and another one in monthB? You want in the end an array of TransactionsEntity right, or an array of CategoriesEntity?

Comment: If it's an array of transactions, fetch on `TransactionsEntity`: `NSPredicate(format: "%K CONTAINS[cd] %@ AND %K >= %@ AND %K <= %@, argumentsArray: [#keyPath(TransactionsEntity.reverseRelationToCategory.name), filterKey, #keyPath(TransactionsEntity.date), startOfTheMonth, #keyPath(TransactionsEntity.date), endOfTheMonth]`

Comment: This is where problems and long searches arose, I can filter transactions with a separate request, but then I won’t be able to filter transactions by property at the same time, since these are different entities. I think correctly? Hmm, you can make a request to filter categories by date, put them in an array and then filter this array and filter it by category name. Need to try.

Comment: While writing you already answered, I'll try